# Storing variables in sessions not working

Tags: sessions

Here is my Custom code I am placing in views custom php field, Strange enough the variables are not storing in sessions except the last session variable, this is strange.

```
drupal_session_start();
$oid = $_GET['oid'];
$extip = $_GET['xip'];
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['oid'] = $_GET['oid'];
$_SESSION['extip'] = $_GET['xip'];
$_SESSION['myip'] = $myip;

print 'oid = '.$oid.' extip = ' . $extip . ' my ip = ' . $myip . ' new order id = ' . $_SESSION['oid'] . ' new external ip = ' . $_SESSION['extip'] . 'new IP of mine  = ' . $_SESSION['myip'];
dpm(ip_address());
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
PHP: oid = 000666 extip = 127.0.0.1 my ip = 197.220.160.38 new id =  new external ip =  new IP = 197.220.160.38
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490253/how-to-save-a-session-variable-in-drupal-7

Comment: given that strangeness of your error, can you please make sure you are cutting and pasting both your code and your output correctly here, because your code suggests that part of the output will be `new order id =` and yet the output contains `new id =`

Comment: I have fixed the issue now, some of the variable names aren't properly called.